# new sys.path in python

Tags: python, import, sys.path

I am having difficulties importing a script from a directory that is not stored in sys.path.  I have a script saved as test.py in a directory called "Development" and am trying to add the development directory to sys.path so I can import a function from my current script called index.py.

**Here is my code for index.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append ('/Users/master/Documents/Development/')
import test

printline()
```

**printline() is defined in test.py as:**

```
def printline():
    print "I am working"
```

**Here is the error I am receiving:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/master/Documents/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    printline()
NameError: name 'printline' is not defined
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you do `import test`, the function you defined is imported into its own namespace, so you must refer to it as `test.printline()`.
2. `test` may be the name of another module in your Python path, and since the directory you insert is appended to the path, it will be considered only if `test` is nowhere else to be found. Try inserting the path to the head of `sys.path` instead:

   ```
   sys.path.insert(0, "...")
   ```

In a vanilla Python, the culprit is likely #1, but if you do not want your scripts to break in the future, you should also get used to #2.

Answer (score 1):

```
from test import println

println()
```

or you can call println through test module object:

```
test.println()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `from printline import printline` then use it.